# rtai_lxrt module not able to insert

Tags: python-3.x, insert, python-import, rtai

I am working on `rtai-4.1` version on Ubuntu-14.04. I am not able to insert `rtai_lxrt` module instead of`rtai_lxrt`. `rtai_sched` is always getting inserted. I don't want to insert `rtai_sched`. Instead, I want to insert `rtai_lxrt`. Any idea how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Do you have a reproducible example?

Comment: yes i have. Any guess what is missing.